# Was Lord Venkateshwara's second wife Bibi Nanchari really a Muslim?

Tags: history, other-religions, venkateshwara

Was Lord Venkateshwara's second wife Bibi Nanchari really a Muslim?

I searched [the wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Venkateswara), but didn't find any answer to my question.

Comment: The actual Bibi Nachair is said to be a Muslim devotee in the Madhura Bhakti tradition of Cheluva Narayana of Melkote.

Comment: Please retain the original version of the question.  In Telugu/Andhra, where Venkateswara dwells, , this supposed second wife of venkateswara is called  Bibi nanchari or Bibi  nancharamma

Comment: The lady who is considered Venkateswara's wife is Bibi Nancharamma. Bibi Nachiair is Cheluva narayana's devotee. They could be two different devotees.

Comment: It is my understanding that Lord Venateswara's incarnation was thousands of years ago....The Muslim religion did not come to India until approximately 600 A.D.....the time periods don't match....

Comment: @moonstar2001 There is also Thulukka Nachiyar, the Muslim princess who fell in love with Ranganatha, the deity of Sri Rangam.

Comment: @SwamiVishwananda The claim is not that Venkateshwara married a Muslim woman while he was moving about on the Earth originally.  At that time he just married Padmavathi.  Rather, the claim is that much later, a Muslim woman became devoted to Venkateshwara, so Venkateshwara appeared before her and married her.  It's akin to how Vishnu is said to have married [Andal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Andal), the female poet-saint.

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan It seems she is the same one who fell in love with Cheluva narayana too?!

Comment: @moonstar2001 haha, I think there are multiple stories of Muslim princesses falling in love with different Vishnu statues, and people use the same terminology to refer to them in each case.  Perhaps originally this happened in just one place, but the same story got copied somehow.  Or it could just be that this genuinely happened to multiple princesses.

Comment: Namaste Lord Venkateswara's time, the religion Islam did not born then i.e. Islam did not exist.
Hence the question is invalid !!!

Comment: @Annonymous The story is not saying that at the time of Venkateshwara, he married a Muslim princess.  It's saying that long after the time of Venkateshwara, there was a Muslim princess who fell in love with Venkateshwara, so Venkateshwara appeared before her and married her.

Answer (score 4):

**Yes**

Bibi Nanchari was really a Muslim. She is not a second wife of Venkateswara as per scripture, but she is a Madura bhakthi devotee of Venkateswara like [Andal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Andal).

This question requires historical references rather than scriptural references. There are several variants of a same story regarding Bibi Nachiar.

One of the story is mentioned in the book [108 Vaishnavite Divya Desams Vol 2](https://ebooks.tirumala.org/read?id=64&title=108%20Vaishnavite%20Divya%20Desams%20Vol%202) published by [TTD](https://ebooks.tirumala.org/) under the category of Temple Literature . The story is as follows

> History records that between the 12th and the 16th centuries, Muslims
> raided the Hindu temples in South India, very many times. Srirangam
> temple was also one of such temples ravaged by successive Muslim
> invaders. Many of the acharyas, the sages, the seers and the common
> people had to make a lot of sacrifices in order to protect the ‘utsava
> murthi’, the processional idol, endearingly called Namperumal. The
> 'koil olugu’ recognises clearly two Mohammedan invasions of
> Sri-rangam. On each occasion, the utsavar viz.Azhagia Manavalan was
> removed from the temple for safe keeping. It is believed that during
> the first sack of the temple, a Nawab at Delhi invaded Thondai
> Mandalam and Chola Mandalam. The marauders entered Srirangam temple
> through the northern gateway of the third enclosure. **There is an
> interesting story regarding the removal and the restoration of the
> utsava vigraham.** It is said that a woman of Karambanur (near
> Srirangam) had the habit of taking her meals only after worshipping
> the God at Srirangam. When the idol was removed by the Mohamedans, she
> is reported to have followed the army upto Delhi and entered the
> Sultan’s palace in disguise. **There she found, that the daughter of the
> Sultan had taken a fancy for the idol of Lord Ranganatha and was
> keeping it all the time by her side**.The woman returned to
> Srirangam,informed the people of the place (“stalattars”) of the
> incident and earned for herself the name of “Pin senra Valli” i.e. the
> person who dutifully followed the God. The ’stalattars’ therefore
> decided to bury the image of Sriranga Nachiar in the Temple beneath a
> ’bilva’ tree near Her shrine. They closed the shrines in the temple
> and went to Delhi as suggested by Pin Senra Valli. They pleased the
> Sultan with their songs and dances and got in return the idol which
> they desired from the Sultan. **But the Sultan did not bargain for the
> reaction of his own daughter who had by then developed a great love
> for the image. Unable to be separated from the idol, the daughter of
> the Sultan, a Muslim lady, made her father permit her to follow the
> idol. In the meantime, the temple servants who got the idol from the
> Badshah dispersed, so as to confuse the army which mayfollow them.
> Three of them belonging to the Kodavar community, an uncle, the
> brother-in-law and a nephew were entrusted with the sacred idol. They
> went to Thiruvengadam hill and hid themselves with the idol in a
> lonely cave in the midst of the thick jungles. The Mohamedan party
> accompanied by the Sultani thus missed them. They reached Srirangam.
> But the idol had not reached Srirangam. Unable to bear the pangs of
> separation from her favourite idol, the Sultani is said to have died
> in Srirangam. This devotee of Lord Ranganatha, though belonging to a
> different faith, is duly honored even to- day. Her shrineis to be seen
> in the northwestern corner of Arjuna mantapam. Even today, her
> association with Namperumal is celebrated and someof the strange
> customs followed in the temple bear a distinct stamp of the pratice of
> the Muslims. She is worshipped as Bibi Nachiar. The image of the
> princess is painted on the wall and the daily offering at this shrine
> is wheat bread**!

Comment: Good information. Up voted.

Comment: :) .................................