# Does BIBI Nanchari has any scriptural evidence?

Tags: belief, venkateshwara, reference-request

Many people in South India believes that Bibi Nanchari is a female goddess married to Venkateswara and belongs to the Muslim religion.

Is there any scriptural evidence for her or just created in folktales in south India like Sasirekha.

Comment: Related [Was Lord Venkateshwara's second wife Bibi Nanchari really a Muslim?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/5360/12304)